# tomtom multisport gps watch [https://github.com/ryanbinns/ttwatch]

Tags: linux, debian, tomtom

I have installed the library from here: https://github.com/ryanbinns/ttwatch

Following the "Setup for unprivileged access", its installed and running from the command line without error, I have created the udev rules as directed in the README.md and created a usb group and added myself to that group.

```
cat /etc/udev/rules.d/99-tomtom.rules 
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1390", ATTRS{idProduct}=="7474", SYMLINK+="tomtom", GROUP="usb", MODE="660"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1390", ATTRS{idProduct}=="7475", SYMLINK+="tomtom", GROUP="usb", MODE="660"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1390", ATTRS{idProduct}=="7477", SYMLINK+="tomtom", GROUP="usb", MODE="660"
```

dmesg output;

```
[54547.729834] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[54547.832071] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1390, idProduct=7474
[54547.832081] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[54547.832086] usb 1-1.2: Product: TomTom GPS Watch
[54547.832091] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: TomTom
[54547.832095] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: HC4046G00051
[54547.839945] hid-generic 0003:1390:7474.000B: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.01 Device [TomTom TomTom GPS Watch] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.2/input0
```

The device is correctly identified but not mounted, I have logged out and restarted the laptop.

Comment: Ryan Binns suggested using sudo [https://github.com/ryanbinns/ttwatch/issues/83] and it works with these rules `cat /etc/udev/rules.d/99-tomtom.rules 
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1390", ATTRS{idProduct}=="7474", SYMLINK+="tomtom", GROUP="plugdev", MODE="660"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1390", ATTRS{idProduct}=="7475", SYMLINK+="tomtom", GROUP="plugdev", MODE="660"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1390", ATTRS{idProduct}=="7477", SYMLINK+="tomtom", GROUP="plugdev", MODE="660"`

Comment: below rules enable watch to be identified without sudo `SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1390", ATTRS{idProduct}=="7474", SYMLINK+="tomtom", GROUP="plugdev", MODE="660"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1390", ATTRS{idProduct}=="7475", SYMLINK+="tomtom", GROUP="plugdev", MODE="660"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1390", ATTRS{idProduct}=="7477", SYMLINK+="tomtom", GROUP="plugdev", MODE="660"`